# Tradingview Pine Script take profit SuperTrend

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Good morning, I have this code where I place a take profit and it closes the operation when reaching the take. but if the take is not reached, it does not close the previous operation before opening a new one. I would like if the take profit is not reached, it closes the operation before the new supertrend signal.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © RingsCherrY

//@version=5

strategy("Heiken Ashi & Super Trend", overlay=true,  pyramiding=1,initial_capital = 10000, default_qty_type= strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100, calc_on_order_fills=false, slippage=0,commission_type=strategy.commission.percent,commission_value=0.02)

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////Function///////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////


heikinashi_open = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, open)
heikinashi_high = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, high)
heikinashi_low  = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, low)
heikinashi_close= request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close)
heikinashi_color = heikinashi_open < heikinashi_close ? #53b987 : #eb4d5c
// plotbar(heikinashi_open, heikinashi_high, heikinashi_low, heikinashi_close, color=heikinashi_color)

x_sma(x, y) =>
    sumx = 0.0
    for i = 0 to y - 1
        sumx := sumx + x[i] / y
    sumx

x_rma(src, length) =>
    alpha = 1/length
    sum = 0.0
    sum := na(sum[1]) ? x_sma(src, length) : alpha * src + (1 - alpha) * nz(sum[1])

x_atr(length) =>
    trueRange = na(heikinashi_high[1])? heikinashi_high-heikinashi_low : math.max(math.max(heikinashi_high - heikinashi_low, math.abs(heikinashi_high - heikinashi_close[1])), math.abs(heikinashi_low - heikinashi_close[1]))
    //true range can be also calculated with ta.tr(true)
    x_rma(trueRange, length)

x_supertrend(factor, atrPeriod) =>
    src = (heikinashi_high+heikinashi_low)/2
    atr = x_atr(atrPeriod)
    upperBand = src + factor * atr
    lowerBand = src - factor * atr
    prevLowerBand = nz(lowerBand[1])
    prevUpperBand = nz(upperBand[1])

    lowerBand := lowerBand > prevLowerBand or heikinashi_close[1] < prevLowerBand ? lowerBand : prevLowerBand
    upperBand := upperBand < prevUpperBand or heikinashi_close[1] > prevUpperBand ? upperBand : prevUpperBand
    int direction = na
    float superTrend = na
    prevSuperTrend = superTrend[1]
    if na(atr[1])
        direction := 1
    else if prevSuperTrend == prevUpperBand
        direction := heikinashi_close > upperBand ? -1 : 1
    else
        direction := heikinashi_close < lowerBand ? 1 : -1
    superTrend := direction == -1 ? lowerBand : upperBand
    [superTrend, direction]
    

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////Indicators/////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

atrPeriod = input(10, "ATR Length")
factor = input.float(3.0, "Factor", step = 0.01)

[supertrend, direction] = x_supertrend(factor, atrPeriod)

bodyMiddle = plot((heikinashi_open + heikinashi_close) / 2, display=display.none)
upTrend = plot(direction < 0 ? supertrend : na, "Up Trend", color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
downTrend = plot(direction < 0? na : supertrend, "Down Trend", color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr)

fill(bodyMiddle, upTrend, color.new(color.green, 90), fillgaps=false)
fill(bodyMiddle, downTrend, color.new(color.red, 90), fillgaps=false)

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////Strategy///////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

var bool longCond                    = na, var bool shortCond                   = na, longCond := nz(longCond[1]), shortCond := nz(shortCond[1])
var int CondIni_long                 = 0, var int CondIni_short                 = 0, CondIni_long := nz(CondIni_long[1]), CondIni_short := nz(CondIni_short[1])
var float open_longCondition         = na, var float open_shortCondition   = na


long  = ta.change(direction) < 0
short = ta.change(direction) > 0


longCond        :=                                                              long
shortCond       :=                                                              short

CondIni_long    :=                                                              longCond[1] ? 1 : shortCond[1] ? -1 : nz(CondIni_long[1])
CondIni_short   :=                                                              longCond[1] ? 1 : shortCond[1] ? -1 : nz(CondIni_short[1])
longCondition   =                                                               (longCond[1] and nz(CondIni_long[1]) == -1)
shortCondition  =                                                               (shortCond[1] and nz(CondIni_short[1]) == 1)


open_longCondition             :=                                          long ? close[1] :                                                      nz(open_longCondition[1])
open_shortCondition            :=                                          short ? close[1] :                                                     nz(open_shortCondition[1])


//TP
tp                    = input.float(1.1  , "TP [%]",                      step = 0.1) 

//BACKTESTING inputs --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

testStartYear       =                   input.int(2000,                             title="start year",                                         minval = 1997, maxval = 3000,                                                   group= "BACKTEST") 
testStartMonth      =                   input.int(01,                               title="start month",                                        minval = 1, maxval = 12,                                                        group= "BACKTEST")
testStartDay        =                   input.int(01,                               title="start day",                                          minval = 1, maxval = 31,                                                        group= "BACKTEST")
testPeriodStart     =                   timestamp(testStartYear,testStartMonth,testStartDay,0,0)
testStopYear        =                   input.int(3333,                             title="stop year",                                          minval=1980, maxval = 3333,                                                     group= "BACKTEST")
testStopMonth       =                   input.int(12,                               title="stop month",                                         minval=1, maxval=12,                                                            group= "BACKTEST")
testStopDay         =                   input.int(31,                               title="stop day",                                           minval=1, maxval=31,                                                            group= "BACKTEST")
testPeriodStop      =                   timestamp(testStopYear, testStopMonth, testStopDay, 0, 0)
testPeriod          =                   time >= testPeriodStart and time <= testPeriodStop ? true : false

// Backtest  ==================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================


if longCond and testPeriod
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long,comment="long")

if shortCond and testPeriod
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short,comment="short")
    

strategy.exit("TP_L", "long", profit =((open_longCondition   *       (1+(tp/100))) - open_longCondition)/syminfo.mintick, comment = "close")

strategy.exit("TP_S", "short", profit =((open_shortCondition  *       (1+(tp/100))) - open_shortCondition)/syminfo.mintick, comment = "close")
```

thank you very much

i tried to use true and false for open position but without success

Answer (score 0):

the strategy function already does that automatically. You don't even need to add strategy.exit lines because once u enter long after being short or u enter short after being long it will close the current trade and move on with the new one I added a limit= line with qty percent profit line so it take profit at a given percentage and qty= qty_percentangelong and short to properly decide how much % of the account u want to use to make the trade, I also added a line for the script to decide when it should enter based on input.source function defval=high and that seems to be the best. All of these are inputs meaning u can change the amount quickly in indicators settings input tab. A few key notes the script uses heikein ashi data for the calculation however it is not possible to use built in functions like SRC, length, sum, alpha without redefining the values with a custom made functions like mysrc = x and then using the new src that uses heikein ashi data. so the script is flawed and only works how it was intended when u open the chart on heikein ashi candles that way all the data is forced to be heikein ashi data meaning u cant use alert() function, however it should be possible to set alerts based on strateggy short and long and exits. So to preference rewriting your own version of length, src, and alpha isn't easy but possible. Anyways I fixed your script and it does work now its actually not so bad when u open the 30min chart on heiken ashi candles.

```
//@version=5

strategy("Heiken Ashi & Super Trend", overlay=true,  pyramiding=1,initial_capital = 10000, default_qty_type= strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100, calc_on_order_fills=false, slippage=0,commission_type=strategy.commission.percent,commission_value=0.02)


//Function


heikinashi_open = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, open)
heikinashi_high = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, high)
heikinashi_low  = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, low)
heikinashi_close= request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close)
heikinashi_color = heikinashi_open < heikinashi_close ? #53b987 : #eb4d5c
qty_percentlong = input.float(100, "Order Quantity (%)", step = 1, minval = 0, maxval = 100, group = "ENTRY/EXIT")
qty_percentshort = input.float(100, "Order Quantity (%)", step = 1, minval = 0, maxval = 100, group = "ENTRY/EXIT")
qty_percentshorttp = input.float(2, "Order Quantity (%)", step = 1, minval = 0, maxval = 100, group = "ENTRY/EXIT")
qty_percentlongtp = input.float(2, "Order Quantity (%)", step = 1, minval = 0, maxval = 100, group = "ENTRY/EXIT")
atrPeriod = input(10, "ATR Length")
factor = input.float(3.0, "Factor", step = 0.01)
// Define input options
entry_source = input.source(title="Entry Price Source", defval=open)

// plotbar(heikinashi_open, heikinashi_high, heikinashi_low, heikinashi_close, color=heikinashi_color)
src1 = (heikinashi_high+heikinashi_low)/2

ha_alpha(heikinashi_open, heikinashi_high, heikinashi_low, heikinashi_close, alpha_type, length)  =>
    if alpha_type == "wilder"
        1 / length
    else if alpha_type == "ema"
        2 / (length + 1)
    else if alpha_type == "sma"
        1 / length
    else
        na


x_sma(x, y) =>
    sumx = 0.0
    for i = 0 to y - 1
        sumx := sumx + x[i] / y
    sumx

x_rma(src1, length) =>
    ha_alpha = 1/length
    sum = 0.0
    sum := na(sum[1]) ? x_sma(src1, length) : ha_alpha * src1 + (1 - ha_alpha) * nz(sum[1])

x_atr(length) =>
    trueRange = na(heikinashi_high[1])? heikinashi_high-heikinashi_low : math.max(math.max(heikinashi_high - heikinashi_low, math.abs(heikinashi_high - heikinashi_close[1])), math.abs(heikinashi_low - heikinashi_close[1]))
    //true range can be also calculated with ta.tr(true)
    x_rma(trueRange, length)

x_supertrend(factor, atrPeriod) =>
    src = (heikinashi_high+heikinashi_low)/2
    atr = x_atr(atrPeriod)
    upperBand = src + factor * atr
    lowerBand = src - factor * atr
    prevLowerBand = nz(lowerBand[1])
    prevUpperBand = nz(upperBand[1])

    lowerBand := lowerBand > prevLowerBand or heikinashi_close[1] < prevLowerBand ? lowerBand : prevLowerBand
    upperBand := upperBand < prevUpperBand or heikinashi_close[1] > prevUpperBand ? upperBand : prevUpperBand
    int direction = na
    float superTrend = na
    prevSuperTrend = superTrend[1]
    if na(atr[1])
        direction := 1
    else if prevSuperTrend == prevUpperBand
        direction := heikinashi_close > upperBand ? -1 : 1
    else
        direction := heikinashi_close < lowerBand ? 1 : -1
    superTrend := direction == -1 ? lowerBand : upperBand
    [superTrend, direction]
    

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////Indicators/////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////


[supertrend, direction] = x_supertrend(factor, atrPeriod)

bodyMiddle = plot((heikinashi_open + heikinashi_close) / 2, display=display.none)
upTrend = plot(direction < 0 ? supertrend : na, "Up Trend", color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
downTrend = plot(direction < 0? na : supertrend, "Down Trend", color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr)

fill(bodyMiddle, upTrend, color.new(color.green, 90), fillgaps=false)
fill(bodyMiddle, downTrend, color.new(color.red, 90), fillgaps=false)


//Strategy

var bool longCond = false, var bool shortCond = false, longCond := nz(longCond[1]), shortCond := nz(shortCond[1])
var int CondIni_long = 0, var int CondIni_short = 0, CondIni_long := nz(CondIni_long[1]), CondIni_short := nz(CondIni_short[1])
var float open_longCondition = na, var float open_shortCondition = na

long  = ta.change(direction) < 0
short = ta.change(direction) > 0

//TP
tp                    = input.float(1.1  , "TP [%]",                      step = 0.1) 

//BACKTESTING inputs --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

testStartYear       =                   input.int(2000,                             title="start year",                                         minval = 1997, maxval = 3000,                                                   group= "BACKTEST") 
testStartMonth      =                   input.int(01,                               title="start month",                                        minval = 1, maxval = 12,                                                        group= "BACKTEST")
testStartDay        =                   input.int(01,                               title="start day",                                          minval = 1, maxval = 31,                                                        group= "BACKTEST")
testPeriodStart     =                   timestamp(testStartYear,testStartMonth,testStartDay,0,0)
testStopYear        =                   input.int(3333,                             title="stop year",                                          minval=1980, maxval = 3333,                                                     group= "BACKTEST")
testStopMonth       =                   input.int(12,                               title="stop month",                                         minval=1, maxval=12,                                                            group= "BACKTEST")
testStopDay         =                   input.int(31,                               title="stop day",                                           minval=1, maxval=31,                                                            group= "BACKTEST")
testPeriodStop      =                   timestamp(testStopYear, testStopMonth, testStopDay, 0, 0)
testPeriod          =                   time >= testPeriodStart and time <= testPeriodStop ? true : false

if long
    longCond := true
    CondIni_long := 1
    open_longCondition := heikinashi_close
    
if short
    shortCond := true
    CondIni_short := -1
    open_shortCondition := heikinashi_close

// Long entry and exit conditions
longEntry = direction < 0 ? supertrend : na
shortEntry = direction < 0 ? na : supertrend


if long and testPeriod and longEntry
    entry_price = entry_source
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty=qty_percentlong, comment="Long")
    long_tp_price = entry_price * (1 + qty_percentlongtp / 100)
    strategy.exit("Long TP", "Long", limit=long_tp_price, comment="Long TP")
    longCond := false

if short and testPeriod and shortEntry
    entry_price = entry_source
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, qty=qty_percentshort, comment="Short")
    short_tp_price = entry_price * (1 - qty_percentshorttp / 100)
    strategy.exit("Short TP", "Short", limit=short_tp_price, comment="Short TP")
    shortCond := false
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, when the take is not reached, I wanted the previous trade to be closed before giving a new signal.

Comment: Good evening friend, can you adapt this code that you made to close the position one candle before opening the new position? thanks

Comment: No because the buy and short signals are based on incoming data. You're only realistic option is to delay the next position opening by 1 candle and use the position opening short/long as the close signal and basically delaying the next trade by 1 candle

Comment: I have a code that closes before the next supertrend signal, and it does just that, delays the entry by one candle. but i need to do signal close because i am using a bot. so I need to send him a close to close the position and then open a new one.

Comment: Yes that's possible so ur saying ur using alerts for webhooks and connecting it to ur bot?

Comment: that's right, I send incoming and outgoing alerts to the bot